# Getting a nested list into a textarea it is not closing all <ul>s

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding and removing `<ul>` and placing its plain structure with its text into a `textarea`. The following works yet it is not closing all the `<ul>`s, not adding the closing `</ul>` basically but it places an open `<ul>` instead.

Here it is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44yb96Lb/167/)

This is what I am doing:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mindMap">
  <ul>
    <li><button class="btn btn-default ul-appending">+ Node</button>      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="mindMapData">
  <textarea col="10" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

The in jQuery I am creating the tool to add/remove nested list and cleaning all the unnecessary html while leaving all the plain nested list and its text:

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.ul-appending', function() {
    $(this).parent().append(
    $('<ul class="main_ul">').addClass('newul sortable').append(
    $('<li><div class="input-group"><input placeholder="Add node..." class="form-control" type="text"><div class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default list">+ sub node</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeThis">remove</button></div></div></li>')
    )
    );
});

$('body').on('click', 'button.list', function() {
  var newLi = '<ul class="sub_ul"><li class="listSub"><div class="input-group"><input placeholder="+ sub node..." class="form-control" type="text"><div class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default list">+ sub node</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeThis">remove</button></div></div></li></ul>';
  var listEl = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    $(listEl).append(newLi);
});

$('body').on('click', 'button.removeThis', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
});

function ul(indent) {
    indent = indent || 4;
  var node = $(this);
    return node.removeAttr('class').children().map(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var value = self.find('> .input-group input').val();
    var sub_ul = self.find('> ul');
    var ul_spaces = new Array(indent+4).join(' ');
    var li_spaces = new Array(indent).join(' ');
    if (sub_ul.length && ul) {
        return li_spaces + '<li>' + value + '\n' + ul_spaces +
          '<ul class="sortable">\n' + ul.call(sub_ul, indent+8) + '\n' + ul_spaces + '<ul>\n' +
          li_spaces + '</li>';
    } else {
        return li_spaces + '<li>' + value + '</li>';
    }
  }).get().join('\n');
}

function updateTree() {
   $("#mindMapData textarea").text('<ul class="sortable">\n' + $("#mindMap").clone().find('.main_ul').map(ul).get().join('\n') + '\n</ul>');
 }

$("#mindMap").on("DOMSubtreeModified", updateTree);
$("#mindMap").on('keyup', 'input', updateTree);
```

[jsFiddle](http://Here%20it%20is%20a%20[jsFiddle][1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 30:

```
'<ul class="sortable">\n' + ul.call(sub_ul, indent+8) + '\n' + ul_spaces + '<ul>\n' +
```

Correction:

```
'<ul class="sortable">\n' + ul.call(sub_ul, indent+8) + '\n' + ul_spaces + '</ul>\n' +
```

You need a slash here: `'</ul>\n'`

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/44yb96Lb/170/)

Comment: sure! I was awaiting for the minutes to have it available :) Thank once again